# python flask doesnt work

Tags: python, flask

Sorry if my english is bad.
ive been attempting to create the basic flask project (went to the main page and ctrl+c ctrl+v the example)and the prompt didnt show anything, it just jumped to the next line of command

C:\project\file.py>python C:\project\file.py

C:\project\file.py>

if somebody can help about this id really apreciate it
i have the venv folder and flask installed
this is the code (it's a test)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Keanu Reeves is breathtaking'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=3264)
```

Comment: This has something to do with your particular environment or setup. The code itself works fine. What are the results of `where python`? And why is your command prompt `C:\project\file.py>`?

Comment: thats literally the folder,also all my test files are named 'file.extension',the command promt looks like that because i use windows CMD since i dont know how to open flask on the python terminal,anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

A Python program needs to be put in a file and executed-- it's what editors are for. You are doing something weird that you are not explaining clearly, but your problem has nothing to do with flask. Try putting the following complete, runnable python program in a file, and execute it. Follow any beginner's Python tutorial you like.

```
print("Hello world")
```

Once you get this to work, replace the file's contents with your example program and you're there.